# C#: Fast way to check how many UTF-8 encoded bytes thats in a StringBuffer?

Tags: c#

I'm building sitemaps and I need a way to quickly check how many UTF-8 encoded bbytes StringBuilder currently contains?

The naive way to do this would be to:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()).Length
```

But isn't this a bit bloated?

Using builder.Length doesn't work as certain charactes resolved to 2 bytes such as ÅÄÖ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(builder.ToString());
```

Unfortunately, unlike Java where there is a CharSequence interface, you cannot directly process the StringBuilder without first converting it to a string.